# Android problems in receiving broadcast from pending intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, wakelock

I am using alarm manager to fire broadcast at specific time. But after testing it so many times, I found sometimes broadcast is received late. Sometimes 5 seconds, 10, 15 or even more sometimes. Specially when device is locked. I have done various experiments. My least problematic code is here.

Even after using wake lock, I don't know what I am lacking.

> **Firing Intent**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), BroadCastReceiver.class);  
//..... some extras
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), code, intent, 0);
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 1000 * 120 , pi);
```

> **Receiving broadcast**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
       WakeLocker.acquire(context);
       .......
       Intent alarm = new Intent(context, xyz.class);
       alarm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(alarm);
}
```

and releasing Wakelock in destroy() of xyz activity.

> **Custom WakeLocker class**
>       public abstract class WakeLocker {

```
private static PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

public static void acquire(Context ctx) {
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
            PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
            PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "haris");
    wakeLock.acquire();
}

public static void release() {
    if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
}
```

}

Comment: are you using Android Lollipop? take a look on that: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1):

According with [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> **AlarmManager.setRepeating(...)**
>  as of API 19, all repeating alarms
>   are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it
>   must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described
>   above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API
>   19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating
>   alarms, treated as exact.

It means you must set your PendingIntent again when you receive it.
Something like this:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    switch (intent.getAction()) {
        case AlarmHelper.ACTION_MY_ALARM: 
            doWhatYouNeed();
            long nextTime = getNextAlarmTime();
            AlarmHelper.resetAlarm(nextTime);
            break;
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

To get next alarm time you can use System.currentTimeMillis() + interval or pass it to intents extras, the second way is more accurate.
And, I'm sure, you don't need WakeLock in BroadcastReceiver.

```
public class AlarmHelper {
    public static void resetAlarm(long time) { 
        Intent intent = createIntent(); 
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = createPendingIntent(intent);
        setAlarmManager(time, pendingIntent); 
    }

    public static void setAlarmManager(long time, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) MyApp.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```